# Laravel validation errors if not using Validator facade

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I have this code for an API, testing with Postman:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|string|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
    ]);

    if($validated->fails()){
        dd($validated->errors()->toArray());
    }

    $validated = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'email' => 'required|string|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
    ]);

    if ($validated->fails()) {
        $errors = $validated->errors()->toArray();
        dd($errors);
    }
}
```

I haven't included at all the `password_confirmation` field in the request.

Validation fails, as it should, but the first dd statement doesn't get printed and Postman shows the homepage.

If I comment the part using the `validate` method on the `$request` and leave only the part that uses Validator facade, dd works as it should, saying `The password field confirmation does not match`.

Is it possible to debug if it fails using `$request->validate` instead of the Validator facade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually *showing* the home page; it's redirecting the user back to the previous page (which happens to be the home page, I suspect; if you look at your browser's network panel you'll see a 302 redirect), with validation errors in the session. Your code never gets to the `dd()` call as a result.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation

> So, what if the incoming request fields do not pass the given validation rules? As mentioned previously, Laravel will automatically redirect the user back to their previous location. In addition, all of the validation errors and request input will automatically be flashed to the session.

Comment: I'm testing in Postman, is there any way to see the validation errors there? As I said, it's an API, I can't test in the browser, at least I don't know how to make POST requests and provide bearer tokens into the browser.

Comment: @alex Send a header of `Accept: application/json` in the Postman request and it'll give a JSON response instead of the redirect.

Comment: the header worked, thanks!